# Show "other" option on search results list with AJAX

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to display an "other" option on the search results box, no matter if the term user is search match or not, any idea how i can achieve this?

I tried with **matcher**, but since data is returned with AJAX it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meditate over https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data

Comment: Hi @Tomalak thanks for your reply, thats to manipulate the results correct? What i need is to add a option that has to be always visible on search results, thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly :) Should effectively not be more than a one-liner function.